# How should I install the latest CMake in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, uninstall, cmake

I am installing Geant4.10.04 in Ubuntu 14.04 and it needs CMake version 3 but while installing it is taking the old CMake version which leads to failure in installation.

Please guide me how to uninstall the old version or uninstall all CMake versions and then reinstall latest CMake version.

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

The default version of [CMake in Ubuntu 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=cmake) is 2.8.12. However, 14.04 also supports CMake 3.5.1 using the package [`cmake3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/cmake3). To install it, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake3
```

It should automatically uninstall the current version of CMake – check the output before confirmation. (Unfortunately, I don’t have any 14.04 machine available to check it for you now.)

If it wouldn’t uninstall the current version of CMake, cancel the installation and use this command first:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
```